# Python data.table row filter by regex

Tags: python, py-datatable

What is the data.table for python equivalent of %like%?

Short example:

```
dt_foo_bar = dt.Frame({"n": [1, 3], "s": ["foo", "bar"]})  
dt_foo_bar[re.match("foo",f.s),:] #works to filter by "foo"
```

I had expected something like this to work:

```
dt_foo_bar[re.match("fo",f.s),:]
```

But it returns "expected string or bytes-like object".
I'd love to start using the new data.tables package in Python the way I use it in R but I work a lot more with text data than numeric.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 0.9.0, datatable contains function `.re_match()` which performs regular expression filtering. For example:

```
>>> import datatable as dt
>>> dt_foo_bar = dt.Frame(N=[1, 3, 5], S=["foo", "bar", "fox"])
>>> dt_foo_bar[dt.f.S.re_match("fo."), :]
     N  S  
--  --  ---
 0   1  foo
 1   5  fox

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

In general, `.re_match()` applies to a column expression and produces a new boolean column indicating whether each value matches the given regular expression or not.

Comment: I could not find this feature, or any string related data processing in the documentation.

Comment: Do you also know how to generate a new column based on the regex?
I use this at the moment, but it doesn't look like the best way wit the to_list conversion: 
DT['new_name'] = Frame([re.sub('some_regex_pattern','value_for_new_column', s) for s in DT[:, "column_for_regex"].to_list()[0]])

Comment: @Zappageck I'm afraid that's not possible right now