# py-datatable 'in' operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datatable, py-datatable

I am unable to perform a standard `in` operation with a pre-defined list of items. I am looking to do something like this:

```
# Construct a simple example frame
from datatable import *
df = Frame(V1=['A','B','C','D'], V2=[1,2,3,4])

# Filter frame to a list of items (THIS DOES NOT WORK)
items = ['A','B']
df[f.V1 in items,:]
```

This example results in the error:

`TypeError: A boolean value cannot be used as a row selector`

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a built-in object for `in` operations. I would like to use something like the `%in%` operator that is native to the R language. **Is there any method for accomplishing this in python?**

I can take this approach with the use of multiple 'equals' operators, but this is inconvenient when you want to consider a large number of items:

```
df[(f.V1 == 'A') | (f.V1 == 'B'),:]
```

datatable 0.10.1
python 3.6

Comment: Pandas has [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for this, but it doesn't look like `datatable` has anything similar. (The `datatable` documentation seems really sparse.)

Comment: @martineau: The question needs a version of `in` that broadcasts over the LHS, which Python's `in` can't do.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494957

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also try this out:

First import all the necessary packages as,

```
import datatable as dt
from datatable import by,f,count
import functools
import operator
```

Create a sample datatable:

```
DT = dt.Frame(V1=['A','B','C','D','E','B','A'], V2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

Make a list of values to be filtered among the observations, in your case it is

```
sel_obs = ['A','B']
```

Now create a filter expression using funtools and operators modules,

```
filter_rows = functools.reduce(operator.or_,(f.V1==obs for obs in sel_obs))
```

Finally apply the above created filter on datatable

```
DT[fil_rows,:]
```

its output as-

```
Out[6]: 
   | V1  V2
-- + --  --
 0 | A    1
 1 | B    2
 2 | B    6
 3 | A    7

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can just play around with operators to do different type of filterings.

@sammyweemy's solution should also work.

Comment: nice play with functools. The next step will probably be speed tests, as pydatatable's primary aim (i might be wrong) is speed.

Comment: This is much faster as the number of rows increase.

Comment: The datatable goal as stated by the original author Matt Dowle is "It provides a high-performance version of base R's data.frame with syntax and feature enhancements for ease of use, convenience and programming speed.". Although this requires the use of two other modules, I think it's the best answer in the interim as the pydatatable team develops the capability to use the `in` operator.

Comment: still too slow to filter 1000 out of 1M row - quite disappointing

Comment: @Areza how slow is slow? what's the benchmark? what are you comparing it against?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that when you pass a list of expressions to python `datatable`, it will evaluate them as `or`.

So you can just do:

```
import datatable
df = datatable.Frame(V1=['A','B','C','D'], V2=[1,2,3,4])

items = ['A','B']
df[[datatable.f.V1 == i for i in items],:]
```

Note that there are some considerations for this: it's not described in the docs and I absolutely don't know if it will always work. Moreover, it also work only to filter one column - if you would try to filter rows where `V1==A or V2==1` the approach with list would create duplicates.

If you would need to do some fancier filtering you can just adjust the filter expression inside the list, such as:

```
df[([(datatable.f.V1 == i) & (datatable.f.V2 >= 2) for i in items]),:]
```

Which will return just the second row from the example, as expected.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work for `!=` ? ie `df[[datatable.f.V1 != i for i in items],:]` Would expect to keep rows where V1 is 'C' and 'D' instead looks like we append two extra rows?

Comment: @Rafael I was rather lazy with my wording when i wrote this answer it seems. In your case it basically filters all the rows where V1 is not A, and then where V1 is not B. You can run `df[:,[datatable.f.V1 != i for i in items]]` to get better idea what the exression returns. In your case, you can do something like: `df[sum([(datatable.f.V1 != i) for i in items]) == len(items),:]` or perhaps `df[[ i not in items for i in df[:, 'V1'].to_numpy()],:]`, if converting one column to numpy is not an issue.

Note that there is a section on filtering datatables via list comprehension in the docs now:

Answer (score 3):

I have not found an `in` function in `pydatatable`; however, there is a hack for your use case:

```
items = ['A','B']
regex = f"{'|'.join(items)}"
df[f.V1.re_match(regex),:]


   V1   V2
  ▪▪▪▪  ▪▪▪▪
0   A   1
1   B   2
2 rows × 2 columns
```

This is from an answer to a different question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031468/7175713). I could not find this function in the docs either. Hopefully, with time, documentation will improve, and there will be more functions included as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the *list of items* is very large, so accepted answer results in python kernel die. My workaround is to create temporary Frame with the *list* as a key and a column with any value for all rows, then **left join** my Frame with temporary Frame and **filter** all rows that are is not NA:

```
DT1 = dt.Frame(A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
TEMP_DT = dt.Frame(A=['a', 'b'], FOO=[1, 1])
TEMP_DT.key = 'A'

DT1[:, :, join(TEMP_DT)][~dt.isna(f.FOO),:]
```