# datatable subset with functools and operator

Tags: python, datatable, py-datatable

Similar to this example [py-datatable 'in' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378782/py-datatable-in-operator) but using another datatable to create a list, fails on the last step:

```
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f, by, count
import operator
import functools

DT1 = dt.Frame(A = range(5))
DT2 = dt.Frame(B = range(3, 10))
sel_obs = DT2['B'].to_list()
filter_rows = functools.reduce(operator.or_,(f.A==obs for obs in sel_obs))
DT1[filter_rows,:]
```

However getting error:

> TypeError: i-expression evaluated into 7 columns

Answer (score 1):

Tiny change, and it works, see 3rd line

```
DT1 = dt.Frame(A = range(5))
DT2 = dt.Frame(B = range(3, 10))
sel_obs = DT2['B'].to_list()[0] ## adding [0] as to_list returns nested list
filter_rows = functools.reduce(operator.or_,(f.A==obs for obs in sel_obs))

DT1[filter_rows,:]
```

Comment: At first, I thought the code in the answer was identical to the last 5 lines of the code in the question. Then I noticed the `[0]`. Perhaps a comment in the answer would help?