# Python Datatable/Pydatatable: How to filter rows in datatable by regex and assign value to new variable according to filter

Tags: python, pandas, py-datatable

I want to assign values to a new column, based on the regex match in another column in python-datatable syntax.

DT[get rows by regex , assign value to new column, ]

```
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f, Frame
import re as re

DT = dt.Frame({'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b' : ['hi', 'foo', 'fat', 'cat']})
DT['new_col']=DT[:,f.b]
DT['new_col'] = Frame([re.sub('f.*','words starting with f', s) for s in DT[:, "new_col"].to_list()[0]])
DT.head()
DT['new_col'] = Frame([re.sub('c.*','words starting with c', s) for s in DT[:, "new_col"].to_list()[0]])
DT.head()
```

Is there another solution without converting with "to_list()" and more within the datatable package (without a loop)?

Here the result of the Regex in this question does not allow for operations on a whole column:
[Python data.table row filter by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621252/python-data-table-row-filter-by-regex)
This is for pandas but not datatable:
[How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex)

Answer (score 1):

I think for now you can go with solution. and the required implements will be looked in and added to datatable as it grows up.

Import libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f,by
import re as re
```

Create a DT

```
DT_X = dt.Frame({'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b' : ['hi', 'foo', 'fat', 'cat']})
```

AND do required manipulations as

```
DT_X[:,f[:].extend({'new_col':dt.Frame([re.sub('f.*','words starting with f', s) for s in DT_X[:, f.b].to_list()[0]])})]
```

Output:

```
  |  a  b    new_col              
-- + --  ---  ---------------------
 0 |  1  hi   hi                   
 1 |  2  foo  words starting with f
 2 |  3  fat  words starting with f
 3 |  4  cat  cat
```